# The cooktop, when it's lit, smells of mercapatan when the 500 gal propane tank is refilled

Tags: smell, propane

When my propane tank is refilled the cooktop smells of mercapatan, only when the burner is lit.  After awhile of using the propane over weeks the smell becomes sporadic, and now that it's 1/3 full doesn't smell at all.

Comment: You only smell it when the gas is burning, but not when the gas is just flowing(unlit)?  That stuff is used to tell if there is a gas leak and should be burnt off with no/little smell.  You should only smell it for the second or two before the gas lights.

Comment: Have you talked to your propane supplier about it?

Comment: Do the flames on the cooktop ever lift off the burners or blow themselves out when you turn the flame up all the way? If so, your propane pressure regulator is not maintaining correct pressure and it needs prompt attention.

Comment: I suspect entrained condensate, which falls out of the gas to the bottom of the tank over time. No fuel gas is 100% pure nor totally "dry"; entrained liquid (aka *condensate*) and debris could be present in various amounts. Ask your propane supplier about the purity of their gas, the concentration of their odorant, and the availability of a condensate filter/trap that could be installed between the tank and the point of use.

Comment: That is what my gas supplier suspects, however, it doesn't explain why 1) It is present only when burning, when it shouldn't be smelling while lit and 2) why it becomes intermittent and eventually disappears as the tank gets lower. My supplier's theory was that re-filling the tank would address it, but that made it worse. He also claims I'm the only one who has an issue with it. I'm trying to find an explanation that answers all the phenomena.

Comment: one possible explanation is that the odorant is suspended in water ... the water protects the odorant from the flames long enough to prevent its combustion

Answer (score 0):

Technically, pure propane is odorless. Sulfur compounds (ethyl/methyl mercaptan, or other) are added to odorize for leak detection purposes. Your propane supplier is *required* to use odorized propane for delivery to retail customers. Reference [Propane Education & Research Council](https://propane.com/)

Most gas suppliers are ready, willing and able to work with customers to resolve any issues with their product; their business depends on customers' purchases. You should continue to work with the supplier and follow their guidance/instructions until/unless you feel in danger and/or feel that any reasonable person would escalate the issue. Escalation would be to the local AHJ and/or area Fire authority.

Note- since the supplier has stated that you are the "only one who has an issue with it" then you should know that some people can't smell mercap-like sulfur compounds under certain conditions (e.g., "[asparagus pee](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27965198/)").